# In Storm is is possible to enable tuple acking for one spout and disable is for another spout in the same topology?

Tags: apache-storm

If i have a storm topology with two spouts, is possible to enable tuple acking in one and disable it in the other.
Why i want this is because i want to increase the throughput and i'm willing to give up on the message processing guarantess for one of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. You can actually enable/disable acking on a tuple basis. On `collector.emit(...)`  you can either provide a message-id (enables acking) or omit the message-id (disabled acking).

For the rest of you topology, you do not need to care about this difference anymore. If you use an tuple with no ID as anchor or ack it, Storm will just ignore those calls and just proceeds.

Comment: So you are saying if i use:
collector.ack(input);
i.e by not adding any ID as anchor, it is as good as disabling acking ?

Comment: Not sure if I understand you correctly. Each tuple that has an ID assigned, must eventually acked. For all other tuples it does not matter if you call ack() or not. What I am saying is, calling ack() for a tuple with no ID assigned is save.

Comment: What does this mean : "calling ack() for a tuple with no ID assigned is save" ?

Comment: There in no error or exception. The call will just be ignored.

Comment: so, if an unanchored tuple is not acked, as in if 
collector.ack(tuple) is not called for an unanchored tuple, that tuple is not replayed ?

Comment: Yes. Unanchored tuples are ignored for fault-tolerance.

Comment: Another query: if my topology has just one KAFKA spout and one bolt. If i do not ack the tuples in the bolt, will they be replayed ? Actually i tested it, and they were being replayed after a given time, so how do i stop that ?

Comment: First, you could if course ack them ;) But if you want to disable fault-tolerance completely, you would need to "fix" the spout. If a spout does not assign message ID on emit(), tuples are not considered for reply. You could for example copy the spout code and do your own version of it -- not sure how difficult it is to do this.

Comment: Okay, so you are saying storm kafka spout is by default set for fault-tolerance. Thanks, that cleared my doubts.